# I read that pulsar 150 have 15 lite. Fuel capacity....but I filled the tank it takes 18 lite...is this possible

Tags: bajaj

Tell me in detail is 18 lite petrol fit in tank of 150 pulsar

Comment: Given the answers posted by others, then the question seems sufficiently clear, does it really need to be on hold?

Answer (score 1):

I too have pulsar 150 when I did from reserve it was 13 litres. I don't think reserve will be of 5 litres. 
May be try one more time in different bunker for reconfirmation.

Comment: Yes, good point are they really selling you full or exact litres - the motorcycle manufacturers are usually very precise with how much the tank holds as most bikes don't have fuel gauges.

Answer (score 1):

The owners manual (and everything else I've been able to find online) says full fuel capacity is 15 litres and reserve is 3.2 litres. Reserve is included in the full capacity, so you're really getting 11.8 litres until you hit reserve.

[Bajaj Pulsar 150 Owners Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/898684/Bajaj-Pulsar-150-Dts-I.html?page=5#manual)

Comment: Clear and good explanation to the question.